# passing an ArrayList to a Java function from c++

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I created a java arraylist of Objects in c++ and passed it to a Java method as an argument using jni invocation api's.

I am filling the array with 2 values an `Integer` and a Java `String("Hello World")`.
Then I pass the `arrayList` to a java method which would just print contents of the `ArrayList`.
Here I am getting the output as:    [[],"Hello World"]

**JAVA code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Agent {
    static { System.loadLibrary("arraylist"); }

    private native void nativeMethod();

    public void Print(ArrayList<Object>data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Agent obj = new Agent();
        obj.nativeMethod();
    }
}
```

**C++ code**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Agent_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{

jclass jClassName  = env->GetObjectClass(thisObj);

jmethodID jmId_Print = env->GetMethodID(jClassName, "Print", "Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V");

jclass cls = (env)->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");

jmethodID mid_ArrayList =  env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");


jmethodID mid_ArrList_addMethod = env->GetMethodID(cls, "add", "Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");

jobject arrlistObj = env->NewObject(cls, mid_ArrayList);

jint jintval = 15;

jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("This is from native client.");

jclass clsInteger = (env)->FindClass("Ljava/lang/Integer;");

jmethodID midInit = (env)->GetMethodID(clsInteger, "<init>", "(I)V");

jobject IntObj = (env)->NewObject(cls, midInit, jintval);

env->CallBooleanMethod(arrlistObj, mid_ArrList_addMethod, IntObj);

env->CallBooleanMethod(arrlistObj, mid_ArrList_addMethod, jstr);

env->CallVoidMethod(thisObj, jmId_Print, arrlistObj);
}
```

I am not able to print the integer that I had sent.

Please give me some suggestions, on what might be going wrong here.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: by that i mean you should edit your post and put your code in your post in a readable manner

Comment: And you should also put the C++ code in your question.

Comment: sorry for the delay I was trying to put the code in the comment's and was not coming up properly...

So in the c++ snippet I create an ArrayList , I get the method Id for the ArrayList::add() method and then call the ArrayList::add method twice storing an Integer and the a string. Finally I call a method Print and pass the arrayList object.